# How to improve IntelliJ Idea 13 Commit Performance?

Tags: svn, version-control, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-13

I'm using **Subversion** as source version control system and it takes too much time to commit **large** projects that contain **5000+ files** despite repository is in the same network with my pc. Is there any way to improve commit performance of **IntelliJ Idea 13** without hardware changes? Getting a notification like **"Waiting for VCS background tasks to finish"** and takes too much time to finish.

**Environment Details:**

OS: **Ubuntu 14.04** LTS

Java: **JDK 1.8** (Oracle)

Idea: **13.1.2**

Comment: Is it any quicker if you do it on the command line?

Comment: @EngineerDollery yes it is better via CLI..

Comment: IntelliJ sucks at SVN,GIT etc.. better to use some 3rd party tool.